# New troy built mower b&s engine surges

Tags: repair

My son called me told me that my brand new out of the box mower's engine surges. Yes I'm going to take it back to the store,when I get back in town, and have them fix it but in the mean time I am curious as to what would cause a new engine to do this? 
Thanks,

Comment: Does it do it all the time, or only just after it's been started?  Is there enough fuel in the tank? Does it have an automatic choke? Is the air filter properly installed?

Comment: All the time,tank full,it doesn't have to be primed if that's what your asking,it surges with or w/out filter. According to Jr anyway. He's pretty savvy with things so I trust his judgment

Comment: Is the grass really long? Are you cutting the grass really short? Does it do it on a smooth flat surface (driveway) while not cutting grass? Does it happen in rabbit, as well as turtle?

Comment: What's the model number?

Comment: Did you add fresh fuel, and oil?

Comment: I would be leaning towards the choke.  Make sure all then linkage is connected correctly.

Comment: most new motors are not shipped with oil, + tester

Comment: It had oil in it,fresh fuel. But I took the top off and I can see this thing moving back and forth while its running.  If i hold it the surging stops. When I push it with my finger the engine speeds up so I guess it's the choke idk.